# Sharing JSON data from server between 2 components

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I posted this yesterday but I have changed so much of the code today I have basically re-written my question:

I have a NativeScript with Angular app using the TabView template and a login form using a modal window over the tabs initially and this appears to be working OK - the login form has no tabs and when logged in I am taken to the TabView.

Upon successful login I want to call methods within the tabbed components and update the respective templates with content specific to the logged in user.

For example one of these is a list of user reports.

I am trying to get a list of user reports from our server and display the list in reports.component.html by calling a service from the success handler in login.component.ts then accessing this in reports.component.ts

In login.component.ts I have at the top

```
    ...
import { User } from "../shared/user/user.model";
import { UserService } from "../shared/user/user.service";
import { ReportsComponent } from "../reports/reports.component";
import { UpdateService } from "../shared/update.service";
...

...
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    moduleId: module.id,    
    providers: [UserService, ReportsComponent, ReportService, UpdateService ],
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
...
```

In the constructor I have

```
private userService: UserService,
private repts: ReportsComponent,
private reportService: ReportService, 
private updateService: UpdateService,
```

Then I have

```
public login() {

   this.userService.login(this.user)
   .subscribe(
        (data) => {              
            //console.log("login data in component = "+JSON.stringify(data));  


            if (data.authenticated==false) {
                ApplicationSettings.setBoolean("authenticated", false);
                alert("Unfortunately we could not log you in: "+data.message);
            } else if (data.authenticated==true) {
                ApplicationSettings.setBoolean("authenticated", true);
                ApplicationSettings.setString("token", data.token);

                console.log("authenticated="+ApplicationSettings.getBoolean("authenticated"));
                console.log("Login success! token="+data.token);

                console.log("calling updateReports from update.service.ts");

                this.updateReports();       

                //this.expense.populate_reports(this.expense); 
                //this.expense.populate_categories(this.expense); 

                this.modalDialogParams.closeCallback(() => console.log('Login modal closed'));

            }

        },
        (error) => alert("Unfortunately we could not log you in.")
   );        
}    
public updateReports() {
    this.updateService.getReports()
    .subscribe(
        (data) => {              
            //console.log("report data in login component = "+JSON.stringify(data));  
        },
        (error) => alert("Problems...")
   );         
}
```

In update.service.ts I have

```
@Injectable()
export class UpdateService {

private _expenses: ObservableArray<Expense>;

private reportDataSource = new Subject<string>(); // Source
reportData$ = this.reportDataSource.asObservable(); // Stream

constructor(private http: Http) { }


getReports() {
    console.log("in updateService getReports");

    let url = Config.apiUrl + "ns_get_reports.php";
    //console.log(url);
    return this.http.get(
        url,
        { headers: this.getCommonHeaders() }
    ).pipe(
        map(this.extractData),
        tap(data => {
            //alert("oi");
            this.reportDataSource.next(data);
            //console.log("reports listing in update service = "+JSON.stringify(data));
        }),
        catchError(this.handleErrors)
    );
}       
getCommonHeaders() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    let token=ApplicationSettings.getString("token");        
    headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.append("token", token);
    return headers;
}
handleErrors(error: Response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
    return Observable.throw(error);
}
private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
}
```

}

Then in reports.component.ts I have

```
export class ReportsComponent implements OnInit {

//private report: Report;
private _reports: ObservableArray<Report>;
private _expenses: ObservableArray<Expense>;
header: string;
report_status: Array<String>;

subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private router: Router, 
    private reportService: ReportService, 
    private expenseService: ExpenseService,
    private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef, 
    private updateService: UpdateService) {

    this._reports = new ObservableArray<Report>();
    this.subscription = updateService.reportData$.subscribe(
        (res) => {
            console.log("reports listing in reports component = "+JSON.stringify(res));

            let data=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));

            if (data["reports"]=="No Reports") {                 
                // No reports to show
            } else {  
                var status_text;
                var status_class;
                for (let i = 0; i < data.reportid.length; i++) {
                    var status_codes=this.displayReportStatus(data.report_status[i]);
                    status_text=status_codes[0];
                    status_class=status_codes[1];

                    this._reports.push(new Report(data.reportid[i], data.report_name[i], data.report_status[i], data.report_value[i], status_text, status_class, data.report_justification));
                }
                this._changeDetectionRef.markForCheck();
                if (!this._changeDetectionRef['destroyed']) {
                    this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
                }

            }

        }
    );
}
public get reports(): ObservableArray<Report> {
    return this._reports;
}
```

The line

```
console.log("reports listing in reports component = "+JSON.stringify(data));
```

is outputting the reports data no problem so the service is returning the correct data.

However the template is not displaying the formatted list of reports. It is blank. The template looks like:

```
   <!--
    <RadListView [items]="reports" (itemTap)="onReportItemTap($event)" >
    //-->
    <RadListView [items]="reports" >
        <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-item="item">
            <StackLayout class="itemTemplateStackLayout" orientation="vertical">

                    <StackLayout class="reportStackLayout" orientation="vertical">

                        <Label class="labelName blue_text bold_text list-group-item" [nsRouterLink]="['../report', item.reportid]" [text]="item.report_name"></Label>


                        <GridLayout class="reportDetailsGridLayout" columns="*, *">
                            <Label row="0" col="0" horizontalAlignment="left" [class]="item.status_class" class="labelStatus"  [text]="item.status_text" textWrap="true"></Label>
                            <Label row="0" col="1" horizontalAlignment="right" class="labelValue green_text bold_text" [text]="item.report_value" textWrap="true"></Label>
                        </GridLayout>

                    </StackLayout>

            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>         
    </RadListView>
</GridLayout>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong.

Hope I have explained sufficiently - please let me know if I need to clarify anything further.

Thanks.

EDIT: October 9th.

Here is the reports.component.ts as it is now. Still not updating the view.

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

import { ReportComponent } from "./report.component";
import { Report } from "../shared/report/report.model";
import { Expense } from "../shared/expense/expense.model";
import { ReportService } from "../shared/report/report.service";
import { ExpenseService } from "../shared/expense/expense.service";
import { UpdateService } from "../shared/update.service";
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router"; 
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import { ObservableArray } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable-array";
import { ListViewEventData } from "nativescript-ui-listview";
import { RadListView } from "nativescript-ui-listview";


import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
import * as ApplicationSettings from "application-settings";
import {getBoolean, setBoolean, getNumber, setNumber, getString, setString, hasKey, remove, clear} from "tns-core-modules/application-settings";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

declare var module: {
    id: string;
 }
@Component({
selector: "Reports",
moduleId: module.id,
providers: [ReportService, ExpenseService, UpdateService],
templateUrl: "./reports.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./reports.component.css"]
})


export class ReportsComponent implements OnInit {

//private report: Report;
private _reports: ObservableArray<Report>;
private _tempreports: ObservableArray<Report>;
private _expenses: ObservableArray<Expense>;
header: string;
report_status: Array<String>;
isLoading = true;
foo: string;

private listView: RadListView;

subscription: Subscription;

constructor(private router: Router, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private reportService: ReportService, 
    private expenseService: ExpenseService,
    private _changeDetectionRef: ChangeDetectorRef, 
    private updateService: UpdateService) {

        this.subscription = this.updateService.reportData$.subscribe(
            (res) => {
                console.log("isLoading="+this.isLoading);
                console.log("reports listing in reports component = "+JSON.stringify(res));


                this._reports = new ObservableArray<Report>();
                this._tempreports = new ObservableArray<Report>();

                let data=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res));

                if (data["reports"]=="No Reports") {                 
                    // No reports to show
                } else {  
                    var status_text;
                    var status_class;
                    for (let i = 0; i < data.reportid.length; i++) {
                        var status_codes=this.displayReportStatus(data.report_status[i]);
                        status_text=status_codes[0];
                        status_class=status_codes[1];

                        this._tempreports.push(new Report(data.reportid[i], data.report_name[i], data.report_status[i], data.report_value[i], status_text, status_class, data.report_justification));
                    }
                    this._reports = this._tempreports;
                    this._changeDetectionRef.markForCheck();
                    if (!this._changeDetectionRef['destroyed']) {
                        this._changeDetectionRef.detectChanges();
                    }

                    this.isLoading=false;
                    //this.listView.refresh();                      
                    console.log("isLoading="+this.isLoading);   

                }

            }
        );

}
onListLoaded(args) {
    console.log("In onListLoaded");
    this.listView = args.object;
    this.listView.refresh();     
}

public get reports(): ObservableArray<Report> {
    //console.log("Where are the focking reports");
    return this._reports;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which platform(ios/android) are you testing this? 
It is very important for ios to provide height and width to the listview or it's parent component. otherwise You code looks fine to me at very first glance.
There are couple of other thing you could to try for further debugging

1. Subscribe in (loaded) mthod of RadListView.
2. Try to assign listview in loaded like this

onListLoaded(args) {this.listView = args.object;}

and refresh the listview by this.listview.refresh() once you have the reports data.
3. Have an activityIndicator first and hide the list. Hide the indicator once you have reports and make lost visible.

```
<ActivityIndicator [busy]="isLoading" [visibility]="isLoading ? 'visible' : 'collapse'" row="2" horizontalAlignment="center"></ActivityIndicator>
```

4. Push data to temp array and once all items are pused, assign that temp array to reports.

```
_tempreports.push(new Report(data.reportid[i], data.report_name[i], data.report_status[i], data.report_value[i], status_text, status_class, data.report_justification));
this._reports = _tempreports;
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for responding. I have tried 3. and 4. without success. I think I need to refresh the RadListView as you say. Please can you explain 1. How to subscribe to loaded method of RadListView? I can't seem to find much on it online. Thanks again.

Comment: <RadListView (loaded)="onListLoaded($event)"></RadListView> and in .ts file use onListLoaded(args) {this.listView = args.object;}
and once you receive the reports data try this.listView.refresh();

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.

Do you know what I should import at the top of the .ts file?
And what type should listView be declared as?

I currently have:
import { ListViewEventData } from "nativescript-ui-listview";

followed by 
private listView: ListViewEventData;

so the line 
this.listView.refresh();  
is producing the error:
Property 'refresh' does not exist on type 'ListViewEventData'.

Thanks.

Comment: Simple solution is that don't define the type of of listView. Leave it like private listView; or

Comment: import { ListView } from "nativescript-ui-listview"; 
private listView: ListView;

Comment: I had to import RadListView as importing ListView was producing an error 
"Module '\"c:/.../node_modules/nativescript-ui-listview/index\"' has no exported member 'ListView'." I have posted the reports.component.ts as it is now at the end of my original question. It is still not updating the view. I'm stumped!

Comment: You are refreshing list in loaded :) I asked you to refresh once data is there. After this.loading = false;

Comment: I did try that but I get a console error. JS: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'refresh' of undefined. And of course if I put the line this.listView = args.object; above it I get an error Cannot find name 'args'

Comment: that means listview is not loaded by the time you are having the reports data.

Comment: I appreciate all your help @Narendra! So the listview is not loading. I thought with data binding it would happen automatically once we load up the _reports array. Can the listview be loaded explicity once we have the report darta?

Comment: Yes it should populate actually and it is also possible to load the data once listview is loaded to view. Do you know how to create a playground? That would be much easier to edit.

Comment: I got it working in the end by subscribing to the service from the reports component onListLoaded handler:- this.updateService.getReports().subscribe(... and loading up the reports array in here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great, happy to hear that. Happy Coding :) you can mark this answer this as solved so that someone else can be benefited from that as well.

Comment: I have upvoted your answer thanks. It isn't visible but hopefully it counts.